# Best practices in sanitizing public facing API?

Tags: python, postgresql, nginx, memcached, pyramid

As a part of our service we are building publicly available API that would let user perform simple tasks (mainly for automation purposes) on our platform (like commenting, closing finished tasks and creating new ones).

API is HTTPS based and requires authorization in form of calling /login with your login and password to recieve token (that can be devalidated in your profile). We use pyramid, postgresql and nginx if it matters.

This is my first project of this kind and I was wondering how I should secure this thing from eating all of our transfer or processing power (some of those API functions are quite heavy).
I want to think about it in the context of an example in which someone makes small error in his script (that uses our API) and it would post comment every second under same task (or list all comments from this task). For 2 days.

If I would force all the reads through cache (valid, for example, for next 10 seconds) so it would hit our memcached servers and not postgres base - would it be sufficient in offloading  this issue (so other users would not be affected) or just silly?

If I would check some kind of timer and wait for at least 5 seconds before making another write (5 seconds between the writes) - would it be ok or I would just kill our server with timer checking?

I guess this is more of a question about best practices in sanitizing public API so it wouldn't bite its creators. How do you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [rate limiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting). Without more knowledge about how your API is written I can't give you specific advice on how to implement it, but your best bet would be to rate limit API consumers so that they can't adversely affect the other users of your service.

Comment: Thanks, this term was the key I needed - I just googled it wrong. Now I found some articles on Twitter API rate limits and it sounds really reasonable.